# vim indentation: multiple languages in file

Tags: vim

Lets say I have the following file: `temp.html` properly indented, it would look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript>
            function blahblahblah(...) {
                doSomething();
            }
            function something else() {
                etc...;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, when I type gg=G, I get something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript>
            function blahblahblah(...) {
            doSomething();
            }
            function something else() {
            etc...;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

as in, my javascript indentation gets messed up. I have `filetype plugin indent on` in my .vimrc, and it seems to work well for my HTML. However, the javascript section of my code is not getting indented properly. How can I properly indent files with multiple languages of code in them using vim?

Answer (score 2):

Indenting mixed filetypes never really works in Vim unless you use a (generally language-specific) external program more suited to that task.

I recommend [js-beautify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/js-beautify) which can format JavaScript in HTML just fine.

Here is the command I use for formatting pure JS (put it in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim`):

```
command! -buffer -range=% Format let b:winview = winsaveview() |
  \ execute <line1> . "," . <line2> . "!js-beautify -f - -j -B -s " . &shiftwidth |
  \ call winrestview(b:winview)
```

Here is the command I use for formatting HTML with optionally embedded JS (put it in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim`):

```
command! -buffer -range=% Format let b:winview = winsaveview() |
  \ execute <line1> . "," . <line2> . "!html-beautify -f - -I -s " . &shiftwidth |
  \ call winrestview(b:winview)
```

Those commands both work the same way:

```
:Format      " formats the whole buffer
:5,23Format  " formats lines 5 to 23
:'<,'>Format " formats the visually selected lines
```